# Httpwebrequest not retrieving Cookies

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created the following code, which as far as Im aware should work fine? It is not receiving any cookies at all, I have double checked with wire shark and the cookies are being returned... this is being developed on Windows Phone 7.

```
            byte[] content = GetLoginRequestContent(username, password);

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginUri);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = AuthContentType;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["referer"] = LoginRequestReferer;
        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        httpWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = content.Length.ToString();



        httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(async1 =>
        {
            using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(async1))
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(async2 =>
            {
                HttpWebResponse rep = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(async2);
                CookieCollection cookies = rep.Cookies;
                using (Stream stream = rep.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    String contentX = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    //if blah blah
                }
            }, null);
        }, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the cookie is marked with [HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) (which is often the case with session cookies) you cannot access them it client side scripting for security reasons. It is sent to the client, the client resends it to the server (if it posses a cookie container) on subsequent requests, but you cannot read its value on the client.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: That's not client-side scripting. That's C# code using HTTP. HttpOnly isn't a problem when you're using HTTP.

Comment: @JoelMueller, of course that it is client side scripting. In this case the code shown by the OP plays the role of a client. I also invite you to read the `documentation` that I am quoting here for you: `If the server sends HTTPOnly cookies, you should create a System.Net.CookieContainer on the request to hold the cookies, although you will not see or be able to access the cookies that are stored in the container. If you do not create a container to hold the cookies, the request will fail. For more information on HTTPOnly cookies, see HTTPOnly cookies..`

Comment: @JoelMueller, please read the documentation before making such statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx. I am stressing on the words: **`although you will not see or be able to access the cookies that are stored in the container`**.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realize until now that the Silverlight version of HttpWebRequest followed different rules.

Comment: No, it doesn't follow any different rules. Do you even imagine the security implications if something like this was possible? That's not possible even in the desktop version of the framework. If it was possible you could read for example my bank web site session cookie and do something with it, like email it to yourself.

Comment: I am however retrieving the same cookie from a Windows based class library and it works perfectly... I dont think that is the problem Darin?

Comment: I find out that the process for the site has to be twice confirm, and what i did is passing a null pageDownloadedEventHandler the second time. After i changed it to a real handler, the cookies appeared. Is it because the async code won't sync the cookies in cookieContainer?
  
  
The cookie container is synced in case of async request too. Probably because you didn't specify a downloaded event handler, the library assumed you don't need any of the response data, so it didn't recieve any of them.

Comment: The above comment was from another thread from someone else that had the same issue, however I dont understand what is being said there..

Comment: It's totally possible to access HttpOnly cookies with the desktop version of the framework. Silverlight runs in the browser, so it has to follow browser security rules, and I should have seen that. However, browser security rules don't apply to the desktop version of the framework. If I wanted to write my own web browser in C#, my browser would be crippled if it behaved as you suggest. You wouldn't even be able to log into your bank in any way with my browser. Desktop C# code doesn't get to piggyback on an existing browser session the way Silverlight does, so this is not a security issue.

Comment: You are correct. It looks like the desktop version doesn't have this limitation. But I guess this answers your question: since you are using Silverlight you cannot access cookies emitted with the `HttpOnly` flag.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm running into the exact same issue. You mentioned the following: _although you will not see or be able to access the cookies that are stored in the container_ Does this suggest that even though the `CookieContainer` is empty (the count is zero whilst debugging), it actually contains the cookie and the server will make use of it on subsequent calls?

Thanks!