# VB.NET HTTPWebRequest. How to display all cookies by name/value?

Tags: vb.net, list, cookies, httpwebrequest

```
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim html As String
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
    Dim tString As String
    Dim Sw As New Stopwatch

  Dim cookieJar As New CookieContainer()


    req = HttpWebRequest.Create("URL")
          req.CookieContainer = cookieJar


    resp = req.GetResponse
    If req.HaveResponse Then
        reader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
        html = reader.ReadToEnd
        '  Main.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer


        tempCookies.Add(resp.Cookies)

        logincookie = tempCookies




    End If
```

Here is my code. How to retrieve cookies from logincookie by name/value ?

I were looking everywhere and I can't find  single solution for this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027740/httpwebrequest-not-retrieving-cookies

Comment: You can read cookies by simple following my solution. Of course you may add some parser and get only cookies without all other headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

I managed to find out that it is very hard (if not impossible) to read cookies from CookieContainer, I read that it might be bad implementation of CookieContainer in .NET

I couldn't find solutions for hours !

But I got it !

```
Response.Headers.ToString
```

It will give you all headers from your response, including cookies !
This way you can easily parse what ever you need from it !

I'm using regex so I will simple use regex to parse all cookies :)